# comparing values from different dataframes line by line, python

Tags: python, dataframe, compare, valueerror

I have two dataframes with different numbers of lines.

`X&Y are coordinates in 2D position`

`DF1:`

```
X,Y,C
1,1,12
2,2,22
3,3,33
4,4,45
5,5,43
6,6,56
```

`DF2:`
`X,Y`start squere next two `X,Y` END squere

```
X,Y,X1,Y1
1,1,3,3
2,2,4,4
```

`part of my code`:

```
A = (abs(DF1['X']).values > abs(DF2['X']).values)
B = (abs(DF1['Y']).values > abs(DF2['Y']).values)
C = (abs(DF1['X']).values < abs(DF2['X1']).values)
D = (abs(DF1['Y']).values < abs(DF2['Y1']).values)
RESULT = A & B & C & D
result=DF1[RESULT]
```

ALSO: i can use only 2 columns from DF2, and in RESULT will be used only A & B, its only example. Right now 2times X and Y showing me the range of values.

When DF2 have only one line, there is OK. But with more than one i have received:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes` 
I know that i need to create a rule that all lines will be compared, but i don't know how, i have tried with diff, but no good results.

OUTPUT:
I need to delete this error and start using line by line. 
For each line in DF2 i need separate result:
for line 1:

```
X,Y,C
2,2,22
```

For line 2

```
X,Y,C
3,3,33
```

And after each checking the line i need to save dataframes results to one file
So in this example in one file there will be``

```
2,2,22
3,3,33
```

Thanks for advice

EDIT:
for Tbaki

```
def isInSquare(row, df2):
    df2=result_from_other_def1.df1
    df1=result_from_other_def2.df2

    if (row.X > df2.iloc[0].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[1].Y):
        if (row.X < df2.iloc[0].X1) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[1].Y2):
            if (row.X < df2.iloc[1].X) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[1].Y):
                if (row.X > df2.iloc[0].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[1].Y2):
                    return True
    return False
```

`DF1.apply(lambda x: isInSquare(x,DF2),axis= 1)# if i will leave this line` here, tk inter will run it automaticly so i my opiniot this should be inside definition.
   Also i dont know how many lines will be in DF1 and in DF2.
Thanks

Comment: What is your expected ouput ?

Comment: @Tbaki hi, i have corrected my question, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Your code and df exemple has difference colums. Also i still don't get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tbaki Sory, i forgot to change it.

Comment: You are using boolean in your code, but the expected output is number, also why duplicated column in df2 ?

Comment: result=DF1[RESULT]  i wrote that line now, its not bool anymore.
in df2 columns are 2 x X and 2 x Y because is range from X to X and from Y to Y

Comment: So you have a set of point in DF1, and want to know if each point of DF1 is in a square of coordinate DF2 ?

Comment: @Tbaki ,exactly. I need to get those squers, and then in second part of my code i am exporting only .max value in C column. for each of that square

Comment: Can you explicite the square coordinate on the df2 ? I'm having a hard time understanding which is which

Comment: @Tbaki , question updated. first two X,Y is start point os squere lets say lower left, and next two X,Y are end. Upper right corner. DF1 are points inside the squere

Comment: Had a hard time understanding it because your coordinate draw a line...will assume what you said then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code, checking for a 5x5 square.

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"Y":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"C":[12,22,33,45,13,56]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,5],"Y":[1,1],"X1":[5,1],"Y1":[5,5]})

def isInSquare(row, df2):
    c1 =  (row.X > df2.iloc[0].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[0].Y)
    c1 = c1 and  (row.X < df2.iloc[0].X1) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[0].Y1)
    c1 = c1 and (row.X < df2.iloc[1].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[1].Y)               
    c1 = c1 and (row.X > df2.iloc[1].X1) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[1].Y1)
    return c1    

DF_NEW = DF1[DF1.apply(lambda x: isInSquare(x,DF2),axis= 1)]
```

output

```
    C   X   Y
1   22  2   2
2   33  3   3
3   45  4   4
```

if you want to keep the max C:

```
DF_NEW = DF_NEW.groupby(["X","Y"]).max().reset_index()
```

Comment: ,i had to do indentation before DF1.apply(lambda x: isInSquare(x,DF2),axis= 1) and inside this definition i had to add before df2 and df1 to value df2=... , and df1=... and i am receiving this error: TypeError: isInSquare() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given) Also i have more dataframes with not only two lines in df2

Comment: Can you post what you modify ?

Comment: i didnt modify much, please take a look. How about using `for line in DF2` in my first proposition, what do You think ?

Comment: @Pawe check it.

Comment: thank You, i will try to do same in my real model. have a nice day !

Comment: hello again , could You tell me , or i will set new topic if You want to. when i am using this code for a button in Tkinter, like this:` b2 = Button(root, text='Convert', font=('arial', 12), command=lambda: convert_button(row,df2))
    b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5,expand=1)`
I am receiving this error: `NameError: global name 'row' is not defined` but when i am leaving empty like this: `command=lambda: convert_button` i have `TypeError: convert_button() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)` ?

Comment: @Pawe why are you using a lambda there ?

Comment: @Tbanki, to callback to the function in my button, but without it its works same, and still errors

Comment: @Pawe have you checked if row and df2 are not empty ?

Comment: @Pawe Sorry, no ideas then why it's not working, try posting the questions