# Calling back the function in button

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, callback

i have received help in this topic: [comparing values from different dataframes line by line, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456526/comparing-values-from-different-dataframes-line-by-line-python/44460153?noredirect=1#comment76025827_44460153)

And i have a code, in my tk inter program:

`DF1 = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"Y":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"C":[12,22,33,45,13,56]})`

`DF2 = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,5],"Y":[1,1],"X1":[5,1],"Y1":[5,5]})`

```
def isInSquare(row, df2):
    c1 =  (row.X > df2.iloc[0].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[0].Y)
    c1 = c1 and  (row.X < df2.iloc[0].X1) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[0].Y1)
    c1 = c1 and (row.X < df2.iloc[1].X) and (row.Y > df2.iloc[1].Y)
    c1 = c1 and (row.X > df2.iloc[1].X1) and (row.Y < df2.iloc[1].Y1)
    return c1

    DF_NEW = DF1[DF1.apply(lambda x: isInSquare(x,DF2),axis = 1)]

    print DF_NEW
```

How to play it with the button in Tkinter? 
this not works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    root.title('title')
    root.geometry("450x150+200+200")

    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

    b1 = Button(root, text='txt', font=('arial', 12), command=isInSquare(row, df2))
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am receiving errors like:
`NameError: name 'row' is not defined`
or then i will leave `command=isInSquare()`
error: `TypeError: isInSquare() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`
Anyone could help in this? df1 and df2 are data frames so i can't put the value inside the command, i dont know what to do ;/

Thanks in advice

Comment: You need to define `row` _before_ using it in `b2 =` line.

Comment: if he would just define row and df2 it would crash after clicking button

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you call the function isInSquare when you initialize your button,

```
b2 = Button(root, text='Convert', font=('arial', 12), command=isInSquare(row,df2))
```

you have to pass a function to the command argument, so don't use any parenthesis with function you pass there

edit:

if row and df2 would be available where you initialize your button, you can do

```
b2 = Button(root, text='Convert', font=('arial', 12), command=lambda: isInSquare(row,df2))
```

Comment: i dont know if I understand right, but when i am giving in a `command=isInSquare` without any parenthesis  i am receiving same error:`TypeError: isInSquare() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`

Comment: you have to design it differently, I don't know where row and df2 come from, so I cannot tell you specifically, but the function in command argument should take no arguments, do def isInSquare(): ... would not crash. Yes, you have to tell where those arguments row and df come from.

Comment: i have edited my question, also with `lambda:` option same errors

Comment: you've said that "row is only inside isInSquare()" and thats not true because you pass it in as argument, so it comes from outside, please post line with its declaration "row = ..."

Comment: hm this part of code has been written in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456526/comparing-values-from-different-dataframes-line-by-line-python/44460153?noredirect=1#comment76025827_44460153 , please tak a fast look, this row its only for this one definition, i dont know what to do more

Comment: So in the code you have copied, row seems to be some part of dataframe, in your code it is not defined. No offense but It seems that you don't know the basics, nothing wrong about that, everyone was a beginner once. My advice is that you should grab a book and read it, read about variables scope in python, functions, probably just reading all of it would be best.

Comment: so how its possible that its working fine ? this part of code is going fine, but i have problems to connect it to the button. Maybe i dont understand well what You are talking, but i will try it on my own like you said. I also dont know how about this "row" this code was proposition from other topic that i paste

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have time to explain fully now, but shortly: if you have a function call like 'print(a)' the interpreter needs to know what 'a' means, if before you call 'print(a)' you have 'a = 3' then it knows what 'a' is and it prints it, and if not, it throws 'NameError: name 'a' is not defined'

Comment: ah i know that, and thats why i was asking about solution with the examples how to solve it. nvm, see ya